# A Question on a claim regarding the notion of "space" in "Indiscrete Thoughts"

Tags: category-theory, definition, topos-theory

I'm reading [Gian-Carlo Rota](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gian-Carlo_Rota)'s book "*[Indiscrete Thoughts](http://books.google.com/books?id=sahFH2CcpywC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false)*".

In page 220 I came across a strange quotation with very few explanations:

> *We thought that the generalizations of the notion of space had ended with topoi, but we were mistaken. We probably know less about space now than we pretended to know fifty years ago. As mathematics progresses, our understanding of it regresses!*

**Question:** What is the most generalized and widely accepted definition of the notion of "*space*" in category theory, particularly I would like to know the generalizations of the notion of topos?

Comment: It's an interesting quote, but the question is unclear and imprecise. Do you want to know about generalizations of toposes? Otherwise the first question doesn't have an answer: there is a profusion of notions of space in category theory, as in other geometric subjects. The second question is a bit nonsensical: if you've heard of topological spaces, you realize there is no point of view in which one defines a space as a set of points. This makes the third question essentially unanswerable as well.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I edited the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for your edit. There is something special for you in this question. I think you will find the point! ;-)

Comment: There's no reason for the poset of generalizations of something to have a largest element.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sure! I mean the largest *known* element!

Comment: There's no reason for the maximal known elements in such a poset to be comparable either. I'm just saying it's common to generalize things in incomparable directions, so "most generalized" seems like a weird thing to ask for to me.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You should become set theorist! I mean the largest known element(s)! A question, according to connections between topos theory and category of sets, should I add "set theory" tag to the post?

Comment: I added "set theory" tag because I think the category of topos is closely related to the category of sets.

Comment: Ali, do you plan to go through all the questions about topos theory and add the set theory tag? If the answer is negative, then this is not a reason to add the tag here; if the answer is positive then please don't and refer to the previous case. No one will be mad at you for not using the set theory tag in one of your questions, and this one really isn't about set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Achtung! Bystanders, don't take this comment too serious! We are talking about something set theoretic in a private language!] I *don't* plan to re-tag all "topos theory" questions to "set theory". In fact as a set theorist I am a bit allergic to mathematical CATs (though I like biological Cats too much!). I'm very happy to see that you used some key words which shows that you got the main point of the question as quickly as possible! *Metsuyan*! ...

Comment: @AsafKaragila ... Thus I think both of us confess that this thread is based on a completely set theoretic motivation and needs this tag! In fact it is just a complicated "comment" which should be added in another set theory post but unfortunately this is not possible by some reasons! I hope we won't need more complicated comments of this type in future, though they are so funny and I like them because they keep my [inner child](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_child) alive! (According to theses comments it seems GCR can add my name besides the others in the page *Aghbaah* too!) ;-)

Comment: Don't think for me, please. If I had any smidgen of feeling that this might be suitable for the set theory tag, I wouldn't have removed it and I wouldn't have left additional comments. This is my very last comment on this thread, take it or leave it, the question has no business being tagged as set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Take it easy Asaf! It is just a tag! I removed it because you don't like it and you have been here for a longer period of time and possibly know better what to do. However I think according to the the *philosophy behind the question* it should be tagged as "logic + set theory + mathematicians + history + soft question". But according to *mathematics appeared in the question* it should be tagged as it is tagged now! A question, do you really mentioned something related to the puzzle behind the question in above comments or I am really losing my mind by seeing such a pattern?! :-|

Comment: See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/higher+geometry.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the best known generalization of a topos is simpler a *higher topos*, in particular, an $(\infty,1)$-topos as developed most thoroughly in Jacob Lurie's *Higher Topos Theory*. To give a vague sense of the purpose of the generalization, an ordinary topos is usually a category of sheaves of sets on some kind of space, i.e. a small category with a Grothendieck topology (this excludes elementary toposes which aren't Grothendieck, but these arguably no longer model spaces.) This is one sense in which a topos is a generalized space.

Sheaves of sets are great and permit globalizations of all kinds of classical abstract algebra, e.g. sheaves of abelian groups and modules, and homological algebra, e.g. sheaves of chain complexes. But if we're concerned with globalizing more modern *homotopical* algebra, then we need to generalize sheaves of sets to sheaves whose values "cohere" better. It's roughly sufficient to think about sheaves of topological spaces. Now a category of sheaves of topological spaces is no longer a topos, but it's possible to formalize the notion of its being a topos "up to homotopy", and that is more or less what higher toposes do.